# Accessing SQLite record from ListView item?

Tags: android

I display the user data from SQLite database using a custom `CursorAdapter`.
Each ListView item is actually a layout with many TextViews.

in the `CursorAdapter.bindView()` method I get database data from the Cursor, and display their modified, prettier versions to the user. Here's what I mean:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    //get listview items Views
    TextView dayTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview_item_day);
    //...

    //get data from cursor
    int day = cursor.getInt(1);
    //...

    //display data nicely to the user
    String sDay = "Day number " + String.valueOf(day) " was a very nice day";

    dayTextView.setText(sDay);
}
```

I want that when the user long clicks an item (I'll use `OnItemLongClickListener` for that), the item will be deleted (easy peasy) **but** I also want to delete the day record from the database.

When the ListView item gets clicked, I have the next parameters supplied to me (in `OnItemLongClickListener`):

```
AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id
```

How do I get to the database record from all these parameters? I could use `TextView.getText()` and apply some string manipulation methods to the result (remember I added strings to the data before setting it in ListView), but I feel like there's another, more clever way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a `List<Integer> days = new Arraylist<>();` to keep days you are modifying and so the index of the list alway will be same as position and you can get your day content by `days.get(position)` and get item from your database.

you should define your list out of `bindView`

Comment: And I'll have to update `days` inside `bindView()`, right? How do I know which position will be decided for every `View` in `bindView()`?

Comment: in your bindView you can get your position by: cursor.getPosition();

Comment: it starts from position 0 to the end of your list and each time inside bindView add to dayslist.add(day). did you get it?

Comment: Yes.. But it's a bit more complicated than that because `bindView()` isn't called for every item in the list, only the visible ones. `cursor.getPosition()` will return the "visual" position of the item, which is different than `int position` in `onItemLongClick()`, which is the "absolute" position of the item.

Comment: Maybe use a Map<position, day>, and somehow convert `int position` to "visual" position?

Comment: I don't know your entire project but when an item is not visible onItemLongClickListener does not make sense

Comment: Right, but say the user clicked an item at position 15, the `days` array will probably consist fewer entries, as the number of visible items. How do I know which entry reflects the item at position 15?

Comment: by Map you can check if any item for position15v exist so if, you can get its content and select from database